# IS Firebase Support For Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I am trying to develop a chat application using firebase for both Android and IOS.
I just want to know that is firebase support for both Android and IOS using xamarin.

Comment: Did you try `Google` ?

Comment: Yes, i tried but not found proper solution for both Android and IOS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a plugin that works for Android and IOS:

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin

You can find how to use it in the description.

Hope this helps and gl

Answer (score -1):

Try this, a library I found on github:
https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin

Here are the steps for installation:
https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin/blob/master/README.md